# Massless particles (special relativity)

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

My syllabus on special relativity says the following:

> We see that special relativity allows massless particles:
>
> $E=pc$
>
> which leads to $M=0$

They literally don't say anything else. I don't get it. How does $E=pc$ lead to $M=0$?

Comment: -1. No research effort. Have you asked your lecturer about this? Have you looked at your course notes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [relativistic equation for the total energy is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation):

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

where $m$ is the rest mass and $p$ is the momentum. For a stationary particle $p = 0$ and we recover Einstein's famous equation:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

For a massless particle $m = 0$ and we end up with the expression you cited:

$$ E = pc $$

Comment: Ahhh, right! I am just introduced to the energy equation in my syllabus, so I completely forgot to think of it! Many thanks for the quick response!